# JavaScript to hide second p tag within a div

Tags: javascript, css, hide

Hi there, I'm after a little javascript to hide the second p tag within a div. If you could also include the onload (or whatever) bit as well that would be great. Thanks.

I've tried this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ .CategoryDescription document.ElementById(".CategoryDescription p:second-child").style.visibility = "hidden"; }); });
```

and

```
$('.CategoryDescription>div>p>p').first().css(styles go here)
```

but neither seems to work.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow, user1041401. Please describe what you have tried and what issues you ran into.

Comment: If tried this          $(document).ready(function(){
  
       .CategoryDescription
        document.ElementById(".CategoryDescription p:second-child").style.visibility = "hidden";  

       
});
        });

Comment: $('.CategoryDescription>div>p>p').first().css(styles go here)

Comment: write like this $('.CategoryDescription>div>p ~p').css(styles go here)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".CategoryDescription p:eq(1)").hide();
});
```

​

Comment: Yeap that was done the trick..thanks very very much

Comment: can you tell me what the :eq(1) means..thanks again

Comment: @user1041401 :eq(1) --> http://api.jquery.com/eq/

Answer (score 0):

```
p:nth-of-type(2){
    display:none;
}
```

Not java-script, but you can obtain effect very similarly in javascript.

**EDIT:** Or to work in old browsers if using `<!DOCTYPE>`, `div>p:first-child+p`

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/Kyomu/PDSMe/)

Comment: but doesnt this not work with IE7 and below?

Comment: @user1041401 If using a `<!DOCTYPE>`, you could say `div>p:first-child+p` and it should work in IE7 and below.